# Use Fitting Parameter from Solve or Nminimize with LinearModelFit

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, fitting

Im Trying to minimize a function by varying parameter "a" with Solve or Nminimize. The Problem is that "a" is dependent on my parameter "R" which is dependent on "a" and LinearModelFit.

Here is the function for R

```
RFunktion[a_]:=Module[{QPunkt1,QPunkt,QundTm,lm},

QPunkt={1,2,3}*a;
QPunkt1={1,2,3};

QundTm=Transpose[{QPunkt1,QPunkt}];
lm=LinearModelFit[QundTm,x,x];

Return[lm["BestFitParameters"][[2]]]
]
```

And here the one I want to minimize by varying the value of "a"

```
    test123[a_]:=Module[{R},
   R=RFunktion[a];
   a^2-R^2==0
   ]
```

Now when I want to solve the equation with
Solve[test123[a],a] I will get an error message, cause LinearModelFit wont recognize "a" as a number.
Can I maybe give "a" an initial value or any other way to fix my problem?

Comment: `RFunktion[a]` returns `a` when `a` has a numeric value.  So `RFunktion` is just the identity function.  So the way you have things set up for any real number `a` you enter, you'll get `True` for `test123[a]`.  Given that, I don't see what you're trying to solve.

Comment: "a" is a function depending on "R" and "R" is a function depending on "a". That being said, LinearModelFit wont work, cause "a" isnt given as a numeric value by Solve. Im trying to solve "a^2-R^2==0", so i want to find the value of "a" for which the equation is true

Comment: If `LinearModelFit` could return a symbolic result it would just return `a` when `QPunkt={1,2,3}*a` and `QPunkt1={1,2,3}`.  So if you want `RFunktion` to return a symbolic result, it should return `a`.  In short for the code you've given, `test123[a]` will always return `True`.  Maybe you've only given a simple example and your real example is a more complicated function.  If so, you need to give something closer to the real function if not the real function itself.